# Fatal error: Call to a member function getElementsByTagName() on a non-object

Tags: php, rss

```
<?php 
$q=$_GET["q"];
$xml = $q;
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load($xml);
$channel=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('channel')->item(0);
$channel_title = $channel->getElementsByTagName('title')
->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$channel_desc = $channel->getElementsByTagName('description')
->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
echo("<b> $channel_title </b>" );
echo("<br>");
echo($channel_desc . "</p>");
$x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('item');
$i=0;
while($i<=9)
  {
  $i++;
  $item_title=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title')
  ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
  $item_desc=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('description')
  ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
  echo ("<b> $item_title </b>"  );
  echo ("<br>");
  echo ($item_desc . "</p>"); 
  }
?>
```

I get this error :

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getElementsByTagName() on a
>   non-object in C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\v9\naloga2.php on line
>   19.

I get this error when there are less than 10 items in RSS.

Comment: What's the value of `$_GET['q']`?

Comment: value of $_GET['q'] is URL to RSS like http://www.feri.uni-mb.si/rss/novice.xml or http://littleshadow.blog.siol.net/feed/ ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `while($i<=9)` then you ask for each element, 0-9. So when you don't have 10 elements, `$x->item($i)` returns nothing, and thus calling `->getElementsByTagName('title')` gives an error since you're calling the method on nothing.

You want to restructure to this:

```
<?php 
$q=$_GET["q"];
$xml = $q;
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load($xml);
$channel=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('channel')->item(0);
$channel_title = $channel->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$channel_desc = $channel->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
echo("<b> $channel_title </b>" );
echo("<br>");
echo($channel_desc . "</p>");
$x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('item');

$counter = 0 ;
foreach($x as $item)
  {
      if(++$counter > 9) break;
      $item_title=$item->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
      $item_desc=$item->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
      echo ("<b> $item_title </b>"  );
      echo ("<br>");
      echo ($item_desc . "</p>"); 
  }
?>
```

Comment: and how can I limit it now on 10 elements? Now I dont get an error, but It also shows me all items in RSS. I only need <=10 of them. Thanks

Comment: Ok, I added back in the feature to only do a maximum of 10 items.

Comment: @AndrewWebb  
I  need to  echo  $channel_title . $channel_desc  directly as variable  without echo("<b> $channel_title </b>" );
echo("<br>");
echo($channel_desc . "</p>"); this way is there is any possibilities to do so ?????

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there are 8 items. Your code

```
$i=0;
while($i<=9) {
  $i++;
  ...
}
```

iterates up to i === 10. Therefore this code

```
$item_title = $x->item($i)
```

doesn't return an element - since the **last element has an index of 7** [valid 0 .. 7].

Try this:

```
  for( $i=0; $i < $x->length; $i++ ) {
    ...
  }
```